# Bulk update run steps in HP ALM using ALM API

Tags: json, rest, alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

My intention is to do bulk update of a test run steps. I have created test set folder -> test set instance-> test run. I can update a test run by posting json 
with url

```
  https://qcurl/qcbin/rest/domains/DOMAIN_NAME/projects/PROJECT_NAME/runs/run_id

{"Fields":[{"Name":"status","values":[{"value":"Passed"}]}]}
```

This works  fine

Now according to the API

> Post, Put To create or update more than one entity of the same entity
>   type, pass the data in the request body. Pass an XML string compliant
>   with the Entities Collection Schema or a JSON string of the same
>   format returned by a GET operation on the collection.
>
> To create entities, use an HTTP POST call. To update entities, use an
>   HTTP PUT call.
>
> Pass one of these content-type headers: 
>   content-type="application/xml;type=collection" 
>   content-type="application/json;type=collection"
>
> Use the content-type header that matches the data you are sending

now i tried many combinations of posting the json for bulk update , everytime i get an error with

```
{
 "Id": "qccore.method-not-allowed",
 "Title": "Method not allowed",
 "ExceptionProperties": null,
 "StackTrace": null
}
```

The json i tried to post to url

```
http://ALM_URI/runs/<run_id>/run-steps


 {
"entities": [{
        "Fields": [
            {
                "Name": "id",
                "values": [{
                        "value": "1219"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "Name": "status",
                "values": [{
                        "value": "Failed"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "Fields": [
            {
                "Name": "id",
                "values": [{
                        "value": "1220"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "Name": "status",
                "values": [{
                        "value": "Passed"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

}

and this one as well

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "Fields": [
            {
                "Name": "id",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "1215"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "status",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "N/A"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        "Fields": [
            {
                "Name": "id",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "1216"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "status",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "N/A"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
  ]
```

}

So far none of them seems to be work. If anyone has done any bulk operations on any ALM API resources please can you point out where iam going wrong in posting  request. FYI this is a **PUT** request . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Macintosh_89: the operation should be possible (singularly). What is missed in your case is the run-steps (in the url):

```
POST/PUT/GET/DELETE    https://qcurl/qcbin/rest/domains/DOMAIN_NAME/projects/PROJECT_NAME/runs/run_id/run-steps
```

If you want to GET some existing run steps then you can even give the run-steps-ID in the end of the previous line.

The run-steps modification by REST API (POST-PUT-GET-DELETE) it should be possible for version higher than QC 11.50, so please have a look at your QC REST library.

Coming to your question if you can send a bulk query for multiple run-steps, I am also looking for a solution, but so far I am using a for loop that is reporting all the run-steps one by one.

So please try before to send only one run-steps dict and afterwards send the next steps to the QC. In case you will be able to send to the QC a multiple request in one shoot, than please let me know.

Otherwise the method suggested above is working stable in my case and it is not such a huge time consuming.

Hope this clarify your query! Ciao and have a nice day.

I had a look and for the HP ALM 12.53 it is possible to update multiple instances at once. Have a look at the below link:

http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/REST/Update_Multiple_Instances.htm

In previous version like 11.52 that I am using, it is still possible to send bulk operations on multiple entities, but remember to add in the headers the content type as you mentioned.

> Post, Put  To create or update more than one entity of the same entity
>   type, pass the data in the request body. Pass an XML string compliant
>   with the Entities Collection Schema or a JSON string of the same
>   format returned by a GET operation on the collection.
>
> To create entities, use an HTTP POST call. To update entities, use an
>   HTTP PUT call.
>
> Pass one of these content-type headers: 
>   content-type="application/xml;type=collection" 
>   content-type="application/json?type=collection"
>
> Use the content-type header that matches the data you are sending.

Last but not least for the run-steps I guess this operation is not permitted. Since the run-steps are maybe considered as subentities of one entity. If I found a bulk way for the 11.52 then I will let you know ;)

Have a nice day and hope I helped you a bit! Ciao

Comment: @Macro smdm , thanks for answer i found out the operation is not possible as you rightly pointed it is considered as subentities of one entity. I would like to have an option where it is possible to do bulk update rather post one by one.

Comment: @Macintosh_89: I would like to do the same, because even the xml coming back from a get on run-steps looks like a normal one from an entity, so it would be not so complicated to put/post same as a bulk on a subentity, but as said this is not possible so far ;) Maybe in the upcoming versions of QC will be possible. I have implemented step-by-step to send each run-steps (but of course it is not a nice solution flooding requests). Have a nice day!